# Opinions about using memcachedb as a large-scale key-value store

Tags: database

We need to implement a large-scale key-value store (let's say up to 500GB) and BerkeleyDB seemed like it might be a decent option, but we would really like it to be network accessible. This led me to look at memcachedb. I haven't found much on the web where people talk about actual experiences with memcachedb, so my questions are, if you've used memcachedb:

- would you recommend using it for a large k-v store?
- if not, why not?

Thanks in advance!

Francis

Answer (score 2):

When I was trying to use BerkeleyDB (Which memcachedb apparrently uses as a backend), I found the insert speed to be atrociously slow. It really was unusable in that respect. My insert pattern and configuration was fairly standard, so I have no idea if it's just a general weakness of BDB, or something strange with my test setup.

One option to look into would be [CouchDB](http://incubator.apache.org/couchdb/). If you need to scale *really* big, there's always HBase or Hypertable, which are both Bigtable clones.

Answer (score 0):

I have used memcached a little bit in one of my projects. I think it's a very efficient and scalable caching platform. By changing small configurations, you're able to replicate the cached objects in more than one server. Facebook uses memacached for their in-memory storage and it's a large scale entity on the web. This gives a thumb up for memcahced.

The only problem I faced in implementation is that doesn't automatically accept objects to store. You will need to serialize the objects before storing which may be a little bit confusing at the beginning.

FYI, there is a nother caching platform produced by Microsoft called: Velocity. You may need to take a look on it: 
http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyId=B24C3708-EEFF-4055-A867-19B5851E7CD2&displaylang=en

Comment: He was asking about MemCacheDB (note the B on the end)